# Why sending and receiving JSON data from the server in IPhone is so slow?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, performance

I'm  making a mobile client for a web site now. And information exchange between my app and server is in JSON (searching users and data on server,sending messages, conversation threading, etc.) But all these features work too slow. I click on the button "send" and then wait for some second before the message will be sent, the same thing with searching, authorization, etc. So I have such a questions:

1. Why it's such a performance overhead?

2. Can it be troubles with the server side or it's JSON parser troubles or may be something else?

3. How can i fix/optimize this? All solutions, advices etc. will be helpful!

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thanks. I really forgot about such thing:)Newbie to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Xcode to debug the app to see whether the majority of time is spent loading the data from the server or parsing the JSON once the data is received.

If it is the first, try loading the data from a PC over the same wireless connection and see if it is slow on that too. If so, clearly your server side code needs optimising.

If it is the second and the parsing is slow, you may want to look into using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) instead of the native JSON parser as testing shows it is faster. You may also want to review the structure of your JSON.

One thing I have noticed however is that connections are slower on my iPad than on other machines. I've noticed this when comparing apps I've developed in the simulator to on the device on the same network and when conducting speedtests. As for why this happens, I am not sure - some form of additional overhead in iOS perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But "instead of the native JSON parser" - I use SBJson parser from github

Comment: Even more reason to look in to JSONKit - testing shows JSONKit is 4x faster on parsing and 10x faster on serialising when compared to SBJSON (previously known as 'json-framework'). See readme on github link above for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I can save you some time - it has nothing to do with JSON. It has to do with how the your app handles requests in general. It obviously needs optimization on the server.

EDIT:

I suppose it could also be that you might be experiencing high-latency on your phone, but again, that has nothing to do with your app.

Debug it using a regular browser and chrome dev tools (in the network tab) - you'll see that the requests take long even on a desktop at which point you'll have to start fishing around in the server-side code to see what's making it go slow (hint: unoptimized database queries are a big bottleneck....but then again, so is crappy hardware).

Sorry that I couldn't be of more help, but without seeing the entire setup of the server and the code that's going slow (not the client requests, but the server code), that's the best I can do.

Best of luck.

Comment: So choosing JSON parser has nothing for this? And i need to look on the server side?

Comment: @Adam this seems more of a comment than an official "answer".  Could you elaborate your comment into something that feels like more of an answer?

Comment: I don't think this is strictly true. I have created an iPad app that loads JSON data from the server. When testing in the simulator it comes back almost instantly, when testing on the device itself it takes a couple of seconds. Both are connected to the same wireless network. I also find that doing speedtests on my iPad I get lower speeds than on a desktop over the same connections. As for why this happens, I'm not sure.